# Se necesita ayuda para descifrar caligrafía de principios del siglo XX

Tags: gramática, ortografía

En la segunda línea aparece el nombre José Camps, la cuestión es saber lo que le sigue pues podría tratarse del segundo apellido. La primera letra parece una "y" que separa los apellidos.

[image: Dedicatoria año 1900]

Comment: No veo ninguna "y" despues de José Camp[o]s.

Comment: Es una suposición, yo dudo de si lo es por no estar separada de la siguiente palabra.

Comment: Es curioso. Habia un participante que hizo algo como 50 preguntas así y no paraban de contestarle sus indagaciones. Aqui tenemos una preguntita, y nada. Vaya a saber por que no contestan. :)

Comment: No sé nada sobre caligrafía española y sería mejor disponer de una muestra más amplia de la escritura del autor pero aquí leo *A mi distinguido amigo José D (tachada) Camps y Frón (?), Su atento/a?, Firma (?),  Día de la Santa del año 1900*

Comment: @Lambie Como aludido, un par de apuntes, primero los textos eran más largos, lo cual permitía responder aunque no se pudieran descifrar todas las palabras; segundo, para mí no es legible la palabra buscada por el OP en este caso. Salud!

Comment: Si fuese un texto más largo se podría comparar la caligrafía pero, lamentablemente esto es lo único que tengo. Como pista puedo decir que el apellido debería ser Catalán y por tanto tener fonemas propios del catalán. Gracias por las aportaciones. Saludos.

Comment: La última frase es "Día de *su Santo* del año 1900".

Answer (score 1):

Las últimas tres letras dicen "ros".
La letra que se une con la "r" es evidentemente una "P" por el largo del trazo y el círculo en la parte superior; el trazo posterior semeja una "V" sin embargo no existen apellidos con tal combinación siendo lo mas lógico que el apellido que se menciona al final de la firma sea el de "Pros"
Este es un apellido extraño pero hay [registros sobre el](https://www.apellidos.top/apellido/pros).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu contribución, lo que dices tiene sentido. Cierto que es un apellido poco común radicado sobre todo en Catalunya lo que guarda relación con el origen de el antepasado en cuestión. Aún así sigo sin entender la tilde que hay encima de la letra ''s'', puede que haya una variante del apellido que se escriba con tilde... Saludos y muchas gracias!

Comment: Otro apellido catalán posible, más habitual que Pros según la página del Instituto Nacional de Estadística español, es Gros, que en catalán actualmente se escribe con tilde: "Grós". Ignoro si en esa época, y en castellano, se escribiría con tilde, pero es posible.

Comment: Yo creo que la tilde, aunque aparece algo desplazada, pertenece a la letra "o", no o a la "s".

Answer (score 1):

---

Que tal? Desciframiento.

Lo que he podido leer;

```
             A mi distinguido amigo amigo D. José Camps y Grós

                          Su attm (Suyo atentamente)
                              
                               Camerdo Monasterio


                            Día de su Santo del año 1900
```

Espero haya servido. Saludos.

Diego M.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aportación Diego, la duda ya está resuelta gracias, en parte, a vuestros comentarios y a el descubrimiento de un documento que lo reafirma.